# Tool that displays outline of HTML5 documents

Tags: html

The [HTML5 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/CR-html5-20140204/) defines an [algorithm for creating a document outline](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/CR-html5-20140204/sections.html#outlines).

I’m looking for tools that follow this algorithm exactly and **display the outline**. Being able to export the outline as text would be nice, but it’s not required.

The tool should support at least one of these ways to input an HTML5 document:

- via HTTP URL (fetching it from the Web)
- via direct input (pasting the whole HTML document)

It doesn’t matter what kind of tool (stand-alone or integrated into browsers, text editors, …; for desktop, mobile or server; GUI or text-based), but please no web services (which *can’t* be installed on my own server).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[**HTML5 Outliner**](https://github.com/hoyois/html5outliner) is available as [bookmarklet](http://hoyois.github.io/#bookmarklets) and JavaScript file. (There is also an [online demo](http://hoyois.github.io/html5outliner/) available.)

When you click at the bookmarklet, the outline gets overlayed on the page (fixed positioned). Clicking anywhere on the page (or again at the bookmarklet) hides the outline.

#### License

It is licensed under the [WTFPL (Version 2)](http://www.wtfpl.net/about/), so it’s [Free Software](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/license-list.html#WTFPL) (but [not](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/a/535/138) Open Source Software).

#### Example

Here’s an example used on the Wikipedia article [*Stack Exchange*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_Exchange):

[image: HTML5 Outliner: overlayed outline]

#### Features

Clicking on an entry **scrolls** the page to the corresponding heading/section.

You can change the **numbering** from single-level (default, see screenshot) to multi-level (`1`, `1.7`, `1.7.1`, …). It can also be disabled.

You can disable the functionality that clicking anywhere on the page **hides** the outline (so you’d *have* to click the bookmarklet again to hide it).

You can enable **tooltips**, containing technical details (e.g., which sectioning element and/or heading element is used).

The entry colors (as well as other CSS) can be changed easily.

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at the Google Chrome Extension [HTML5 Outliner](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/html5-outliner/afoibpobokebhgfnknfndkgemglggomo).  This tool is also available as a bookmarklet, JavaScript, Opera extension, and an experimental Firebug extension: https://code.google.com/p/h5o/.

[image: HTML5 Outliner tooltip UI]

Comment: It seems that this tool is also available as bookmarklet, JavaScript, Opera extension, and an experimental Firebug extension: http://code.google.com/p/h5o/ -- The last [releases](http://code.google.com/p/h5o/downloads/list) seem to be from 2010, though; but then I don’t know if the outline algorithm was changed in this time.

Comment: @braveterry would you add the info from unors comment to the answer so it gets better visible (not all users read comments)

Comment: I just tested it (Chromium extension and bookmarklet). It seems to work great for most cases, but it doesn’t follow the algorithm 100% correctly. Examples: (1) Elements with the `hidden` attribute should not contribute to the outline, but in h5o they do. (2) The `dialog` element is a sectioning root, but h5o doesn’t handle it like that.

Comment: Just a name, a link, and a screenshot do not make a good answer. Please see [this meta post](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/356/185) concerning what is considered a high-quality answer on this site.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 2):

The current backend code of the [W3C HTML Checker](https://validator.w3.org/nu/) has a **Show outline** feature that conforms to the outline algorithm in the HTML spec.

I’ve written [instructions on how you can easily run your own instance of the checker locally](http://validator.github.io/validator/#standalone).

You can have it downloaded and run within minutes (if not seconds) with just two commands:

```
wget https://sideshowbarker.net/releases/jar/vnu.jar
java -cp ./vnu.jar nu.validator.servlet.Main 8888
```

Then open http://localhost:8888/ in your browser and you’ll have a form you can use for either checking documents by specifying their URLs or by file upload.

To get an outline for a document, just check the **outline** checkbox in that form.